# Which thread will be blocked by sleep: in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Which thread is blocked by Swift's `sleep:` method?

```
let customConcurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "CustomConcurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
customConcurrentQueue.async {
    sleep(5)
    print("1")
}
print("2")
```

Will sleep method block the Main thread also?

Comment: Well in which order does it execute the `print` statements? `1 2` or `2 1`?

Comment: The block inside your customConcurrentQueue will be queued immediately, but obviously it won't choke/block its current thread, because it's async. Then, immediately print "2" would happen, it would choke/block its current queue until it finishes printing and 5 seconds later on the customConcurrentQueue print "1", the *sleep* happens onto the customConcurrentQueue, not on the thread you wrote `customConcurrentQueue.async {
    sleep(5)
    print("1")
}
print("2")
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the main thread will not be blocked.

It is because you are calling an `async` block on the `customConcurrentQueue`, which allows the main thread to continue running immediately. If you used `sync` instead, the main thread would wait until the `sync` block is finished running.